# Affecting Java classes without changing the code

Tags: java, oop

I am using a Java library, with two classes `Foo` and `FooConfig`; I am unable to change the library code, but can read it. Here are the relevant functions of a `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    /** Install a configuration on this Foo */
    void configure(FooConfig config);

    /** Uninstall the current configuration */
    void unconfigure();
}
```

The library creates `Foo`s at times I can't control, and installs configurations shortly after creation. A `Foo` can only have on configuration at a time. I would like to use `MyFooConfig`, inherited from `FooConfig`, instead. Is there any way to intercept the `configure` call, or the `FooConfig` constructor, or anything like that to use my class instead?

My current solution is to get a reference to the `Foo` object shortly after its creation and configuration, uninstall the current configuration,and then install a `MyFooConfig` instead. This could work, but it causes several different problems (both with being a difficult solution to implement and with some inelegancies which can't be hidden from the user). Is there a better way, preferably using features of Java to intercept the constructor call to `FooConfig`, or the `configure` method, or something similar? The closest thing to an alternate solution I've found is to try to use a different `ClassLoader` to replace `FooConfig` with my own class behind the scenes, but I don't actually have access to the object that creates the `FooConfig`s so I don't think that's possible. Other things that looked promising but ultimately didn't pan out are proxy objects (I can't make the `Foo`s be proxy objects), seeing if I could somehow get notified when a `FooConfig` was created without actually intercepting the constructor (so I could find its `Foo` and reconfigure it in a better way than I`m currently doing), and changing the library code itself (which, for various reasons, turns out to not be possible).

I don't know much about aspect-oriented programming, but it seems like it could help. Unfortunately, all the AOP Java tools seem to require special compilers, and I don't want to change the build process.

Comment: Basically, if you can't do it with overloading and you can't do it with "reflections" then you can't do it.

Comment: The other options are probably worse then aop. one might be a byte code manipulation library like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/).